# Why isn't this picking up commands issued to the console?

Tags: javascript, security, browser, xss

In an attempt to prevent clever visitors from cheating the system on my site, I'm trying to secretly record and send to the server anything typed into the browser's command line. The relevant chunk of code is

```
window.console.command = function (thiscmd) {
    alert('thiscmd = ' + thiscmd); // test
    if (SG.consoleCommands) SG.consoleCommands += thiscmd; 
}
```

but the `alert` isn't working. I'm using Google Chrome, but tried in IE as well.

**Relevant fiddle:** Go to http://jsfiddle.net/63cL1qoe/ and typed var `x = 69;` in the console and click enter. Nothing happens.

What am I missing?

Comment: how do you expect your `window.console.command` function to be executed. whatis SG.consoleCommands?

Comment: @JaromandaX Don't worry about that line. I was pasting it directly from my project and it isn't necessarily relevant to immediate question. I'm just looking how to detect that something was even typed in, and hopefully get that something as a string.

Comment: simple answer, you can't intercept the console from a web page

Comment: Why do you think the `console` object has a `command` method that you can overwrite? Have you got a link to any doco supporting that idea?

Comment: @GregorMcGregor I remember cut-pasting that from StackOverflow a while back. I'll try to find the original thread.